# gcloud container VMs logging strategy

Tags: gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an instance group of `Container VMs` running my app on a docker container.

I am trying to find a good strategy to manage the application logs for docker + MEAN + `Google Cloud Compute Machines`.

I can see the logs on individual containers running `docker logs [container_id]`.

However, if I stop and start the VM I lose those logs. I also have VMs dynamically added by `Auto scaler` and would like to have a convenient way to access the logs.

Stack is `MEAN` and Logging tool is `bunyan`.

Is is possible to centralize or combine the logs from all VMS in one persistent location?

any suggestions?

UPDATES:
I installed `fluentd` agent and now I can see logs when I manually run thins on the shell: `logger "some message for testing"`

However, the logs from my `container vm` from my docker container never shows up on logs.

I still don't know how to get those docker logs to turn up on google cloud logs. It is supposed to be automatically collected.

cheers
Leo

Answer (score 2):

Here is a yaml, Dockerfile and conf for a fluentd pod inside kubernetes.

- Adjust the yaml to mount a disk:
  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/tree/master/contrib/logging/fluentd-sidecar-gcp
- Then adjust the config to log to the disk.
- Build the container with the new configuration.
- Deploy the new container.

Comment: Found an even better kubernetes-docs tutorial: Logs ingested into Google Cloud Logging may be exported to various other destinations including Google Cloud Storage buckets and BigQuery. Use the Exports tab in the Cloud Logging console to specify where logs should be streamed to. You can also follow this link to the settings tab. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/logging.md

Comment: This page https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/tree/master/contrib/logging/fluentd-sidecar-gcp says:

"This shouldn't be necessary if your container writes its logs to stdout or stderr, since the Kubernetes cluster's default logging infrastructure will collect that automatically"

I log to stdout:
`var log = bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'myapp'
});`

At Google Cloud Console, under: Monitoring > Logs
I don't see any application log. I can only see specific Google cloud logs.

Basically I want to do is `log.info('my server error', error)`
and be able to see this at Google cloud.

Comment: I have a jenkins container inside gcloud and i can see it logging inside the console. Can you see your logs when using: docker logs yourcontainer?

Comment: I now have a logging solution. I am using fluentd inside a side-car container that i can attach to any container. I am using loggly-plugin to log my cloud container to loggly.com. Documentation for both can be found here: https://github.com/blacklabelops/fluentd/tree/master/fluentd-loggly